# Is restoring WhatsApp media (photos) from Google Drive enough, or should I also sync it with Google Photos?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, photos, google-photos

I have a Google Drive backup for my WhatsApp, and I think it also includes media (photos). But my phone is also filled with WhatsApp photos and I want to back it up to Google Photos. Now I am confused as to how the restore will work in case I lost my phone.

Will I only need to restore from Google Drive and it will include all the media? Or will I have to synch it with Google Photos as well?

Comment: Anything under `/whatsapp/Media` is part of WhatsApp GD backup.

Comment: @defalt at least if Settings > Chats > Backup > Including Videos is switched on.

Answer (score 0):

If you backup it to Google drive it will include all the media